# How to update version on Heroku?

Tags: github, heroku, errbit

I used the deploy on Heroku button of https://github.com/errbit/errbit .

Worked great for a long time (version 0.7.0-dev) , now I'm getting a deprecation warning from GitHub:

> [GitHub API] Deprecation notice for authentication via URL query parameters

The instructions at https://github.com/errbit/errbit#upgrading doesn't seem to work with Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the way to upgrade would be to git clone errbit at the tagged release version you want to run, and then use the heroku command line tool to add a git remote for your heroku app. From that point you would manage the upgrade by pushing to the heroku remote.

Here's a rough guide, but you'll want to be somewhat familiar with git and the heroku command line tools.

```
git clone git@github.com:errbit/errbit.git
cd errbit
heroku git:remote -a your-app-name
git push heroku origin/v0.9.0:master
```

See also https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#for-an-existing-heroku-app